# ctime(x) = ctime(x-600) why?

Tags: c++, ctime

I get the same string result for curTime and pastTime when I use "ctime" even though the actual values at curTime and pastTime are different by 600 seconds.

How am I getting the same string time for both when using ctime?

thx

```
struct _timeb timebuffer;

_ftime(&timebuffer);

const time_t  curTime = (const time_t)timebuffer.time;
const time_t  pastTime = curTime - (const time_t)600;

s.Format("%d  %s\n%d  %s", curTime, ctime(&curTime), pastTime, ctime(&pastTime) );
MessageBox(s);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`ctime` returns a string that can be statically allocated.

So one of your two calls is overwriting the string that the other one generates.
You'll need to split that into two print statements, or copy (string copy) the return values of `ctime` into temporaries.

Comment: ...or use `strftime`, which requires you to manage the buffer.

Comment: I ended up using sprintf for each.  But strftime looks easier to use by only using what I want to display.  thx